# React Router links based on some name from another component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, react-native, react-router

Is this possible to create links based on some title from component?

Example:

```
<Route path={some-name-from-component} component={Example}/>

class Example extends Component{
render() {
   SomeArr.map(el => el.name}
 }
}
```

I want that el.name go to my path, is that possible?
I read about /:id option, but i don't see how can i do it in this case.

Answer (score 0):

You can’t work backward for a route. That would be child to parent component which wont run until the route is hit.

Can you not run the array map at a higher level?

```
arr.map(el => <Route path={el.name} component={Example} />)
```